# Плавный скрол к якорю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть плавный скрол к якорю по слыке http://test3#e3, что нужно сделать что бы работало с http://test3/#e3 ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){ //берем все ссылки атрибут href которых начинается с #
  if(document.getElementById($(this).attr('href').substr(1)) != null) { //на странице есть элемент с нужным нам id
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top }, 2000); // анимируем скролл к элементу
  }     
  return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если на jQuery, для всех якорных ссылок на текущей странице:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Подпишись на `hashchange`, сделай `preventDefault` и скроллься.